# How to save each slide of a gif animation to png in ImageReady

Tags: images, png, animation, gif, image-editing

Can someone please explain me how to save each slide of a `gif` animation as a `png` file in Adobe ImageReady?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's been quite a while since I've launched Imageready and no longer have it available to test.

By "slide" I assume you mean animation frame. In the animation panel There may be an option to save frames. If not, there **is** an option to flatten frames to layers. This would create a new layer for each frame of the animation. You could then simply export or save each layer as an individual image.

Comment: Please explain the down vote or provide an answer. Thanks.